Python automating ant build
I want to automate java ant build using python, I can't set environment vars on my PC, so I've tried the following script, but it does not find ant. If I run in windows cmd it works. How can I solve?
import subprocess
from typing import List

ant_home = "C:\\Apps\\ant"
java_home = "C:\\Apps\\Java\\jdk-17"

def java_build_ant(project_path: str, build_file: str = "build.xml") -> str:
    cmd = [
        "cmd.exe", "/c",
        f"set JAVA_HOME={java_home} &&"
        f"SET ANT_HOME={ant_home} &&"
        f"SET PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\\bin &&"
        f"cd {project_path} &&"
        f"ant -f {build_file}"
    ]

    result = subprocess.run(cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)

    if result.returncode == 0:
        return f"Build successful!\n\nOutput:\n{result.stdout}"
    else:
        return f"Build failed!\n\nError:\n{result.stderr}"


Don't use Python, just write a simple Batch file that performs these steps (you basically already have those steps).

I need to use this function by an autogen agent @mark rotteveel

Then call the Batch file from your Python script?

Yeah, that's what I did, it works but I did some modifications

Create an ant_build.bat
set buildFile=build.xml
if not "%3" == "" set buildFile=%3

set JAVA_HOME=%1
SET ANT_HOME=C:\Apps\ant
SET PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin
cd %2
ant -f %buildFile%

Edit python code:
def java_build_ant(project_path: str, build_file: str = "build.xml") -> str:
    cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    result = subprocess.run(["cmd.exe", "/c", f"cd {cwd} && .\\ant_build.bat {java_home} {project_path} {build_file}"],
                   capture_output=True, text=True)
    if result.returncode == 0:
        return f"Build successful!\n\nOutput:\n{result.stdout}"
    else:
        return f"Build failed!\n\nOutput:\n{result.stdout}\nError:\n{result.stderr}"

